# How to setup Nginx with React/React router?

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, react-router

On my DO droplet I have configured nginx to proxy to two different apps. One is a static react app and everything works great here but for the React/Express app I am getting unexpected token < error.

My app works fine without Nginx. If I go to `my_ip:5001` everything is good but if I try to do it with Nginx this error occurs.

This is my Nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location /static {

           proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

          location /trello {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;

           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }
}
```

I don't know if `index.js` file in the express app would help.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./routes/api");
const HttpError = require("./models/httpError");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
;
const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client", "build")));
app.use(express.static("public"));
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://164.92.132.26:27017/reaction")
  .then(() => console.log(`Database connected successfully`))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/api", routes);

 app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"));
});



//app.use((req, res, next) => {
//      console.log("first here",path.join(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"));
//  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"));
//});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new HttpError("Could not find this route.", 404);
  throw error;
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(err);
  }
  res.status(err.code || 500);
        console.log("here")
  res.json({ error: err.message || "An unknown error occured" });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Anyway, to repeat, the app works if I don't use Nginx, but with it, for some reason, it is giving `unexpected token <` error. I am assuming it has something to do with the `index.html` file in the `build` folder due to react router but I am not sure why.

`main.chunk.js` file is throwing an error and it is this file when I open it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing the nginx config's trello location block's `proxy_pass` from `http://localhost:5001;` to `http://localhost:5001/;`. With the / at the end, nginx strips off the matched prefix (/trello). That way, the requests to your express app aren't `/trello/api/foo`, but `/api/foo`

Comment: Same thing. It is something with react, router and Nginx config

Comment: Which request is giving that error? What's the path? If you look at the request with your browser's developer tools' network tab, what's in the response data? The index, or an error path from nginx?

Comment: You could also add a middleware before any other middleware in your express app which logs all details about the `req` to the console so you can see what the path is etc.

Comment: I've tried it with another react app without router and same issue. 

The error is Uncaught SyntaxError, expected expression got `<` in `main.chunk.js`.

Comment: Ah, I see. The built index file is missing the path prefix for the URLs of the assets. If you're using Create React App, see: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: Can you be more specific or provide an example? I am not sure what the exact issue is so docs are overwhelming

Comment: Also, why would it work if I just directly access at port 5001,   my_ip_address:5001

Comment: The issue is probably that the static react build tries to load e.g. `<script src="/static/main.chunk.js">` which is missing the `/trello`. You need to indicate a base path or a PUBLIC_URL or something like that in whatever you're using to build your react app (react-scripts and create react app?)

Comment: I've tried to set homepage in `package.json` to "." as suggested in some posts, also to `"./trello"` no luck.

Comment: The main issue I see is how come the app works if I go directly to that port but it doesn't work with Nginx? Feels like it is a config Nginx issue.

Comment: It's because if you go directly to ip:5001, your browser requests ip:5001/static/js/bundle.js or whatever. The path your app sees for the request is /static/js/bundle.js and it serves it properly. However, when going to the nginx address, tour browser still requests the same path so for example nginx:80/static/js/bundle.js, but your nginx sees /static and serves the bundle from the server where /static is proxied to by nginx. The wrong app, then. You need to find a way to change that /static/js/bundle.js to /trello/static/js/bundle.js in the index.html.

Comment: Are you using create react app? Try `"homepage": "example.com/trello"` and **rebuild** the app.

Comment: same thing unfortunately. I am using create-react-app

Comment: Does it change the URLs in the index.html at least?

Comment: It works not but it doesn't send request to correct api endpoint. Going to ask another question. Thank you